# regex - How do I replace text between quotes that satisfy certain conditions

Tags: python, regex

Say I have the following input string:

```
s = ''' not this "not this either", "but {this}"'''
```

And I want to replace it to:

```
''' not this "not this either", f"but {this}"'''
```

The rule is that I add an `f`in front of an open double quote only if the open double quote and the corresponding closing double quote enclose a pair of `{` and `}`.

Currently I can only do

```
p = re.compile('".*?"')
matches = p.findall(s)
for match in matches:
    if '{' in match and '{' in match:
        s = s.replace(match, 'f'+match)
```

I am wondering if there is any cleaner way to do it.

Comment: How is this valid Python? `AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'contains'`. Also, there is a missing colon at the end of the if statement.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a positive lookahead:

```
s = ''' not this "not this either", "but {this}"'''
p = re.compile('(?="[A-Za-z ]+?{\w+}")')
new_s = p.sub('f',s)
print (new_s)
```

Result:

```
not this "not this either", f"but {this}"
```